# Python : Converting time string with different timezone to host timezone datetime object?

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, timezone

My host has timezone UTC and I am trying to convert PDT time string to date time object,
I have used the below given code-snippet but it didn't worked

```
datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime('Thu Jun 09 08:28:12 PDT 2016', '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y')
```

I am getting this error -

> ValueError: time data 'Thu Jun 09 08:28:12 PDT 2016' does not match
>   format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y'

I got it that it's because my host's timezone is UTC. But I am not able to figure out the way to solve this issue. I need to convert PDT string to UTC aware timezone.

I am blocked. Any help Appreciated.

Comment: Where is the local time object being generated from? The `pdt` part is why it's not working correctly.

Comment: my host is on UTC where i am running the above code, and time string i am getting from another service

Comment: You're likely going to need to localize the PDT portion or convert it before trying to format it with datetime.

Comment: how to localize it ? what do you mean by formatting it ?

Comment: You can also do it using `parser.parse(date_string)` imported from `dateutil`

Comment: Which gives you in this format : `2016-06-09 08:28:12`

Comment: @NickilMaveli i tried  utc_dateObj = dateObj.astimezone(timezone('UTC')) after parsing using dateutil. but it is giving error then as - "ValueError: astimezone() cannot be applied to a naive datetime"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have many different values in `TZINFOS`. Which will support your code not to fail if it encounters different timezones.

Parse the string then converting PDT datetime to UTC is explained below.

```
import pytz
import dateutil.parser
TZINFOS = { 'PDT': pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')}
datetime_obj = dateutil.parser.parse('Thu Jun 09 08:28:12 PDT 2016', tzinfos= TZINFOS)
print datetime_obj
datetime_in_utc = datetime_obj.astimezone(pytz.utc) # convert to UTC
print datetime_in_utc
```

And `print pytz.all_timezones` will give you all possible values.

Comment: how come this specific structure "TZINFOS = { 'PDT': pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')} "  of TZINFOS work. Can you explain ?

Comment: This argument maps time zone names to timezones see http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html

Comment: thanks for the solution !